# Macro Run only a three lines of code and then stops working without any error messages

Tags: excel, vba, file, directory, cell

I have the code that is working perfectly, but now it doesn't open the code line when comes to open the file from directory. It opens file, looks for the values in the column A, then it defines the next emty column in range, and then stops suddenly without any error messages. I have the following code:

```
Sub CENTRAL()

Dim cell3 As Range
Dim FileName As String
Dim CellName As String
Dim Fpath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim SumResult As Double



Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\SKY\Desktop\Dom\CENTRAL.xlsx"




For Each cell3 In ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)

finalcolumn = 1 + ActiveSheet.Cells(cell3.row, 14).End(xlToLeft).Column <-- it is executing the code till here

MsgBox finalcolumn <--- to check if it is working

Fpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" <----- from this part macro stops to work
CellName = cell3.Value

FileName = Dir(Fpath & "\*" & CellName & ".xlsx")
Select Case True
Case Trim(cell3.Value) = "Total"
Case Trim(cell3.Value) <> "" And Left (FileName,14) Like "*" & CellName & "*"

Workbooks.Open FileName:=Fpath & FileName
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
SumResult = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B6"))
Totalsum = Totalsum + SumResult

Windows("CENTRAL.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(cell3.row, finalcolumn), Cells(cell3.row, finalcolumn)).Value = Totalsum
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wb.Close



End Select

Next cell3



End Sub
```

Comment: If there are less than 14 columns in Cell3.Row then this instruction would be impossible to fulfill, `ActiveSheet.Cells(Cell3.row, 14).End(xlToLeft).Column`. Try `Cells(Cell3.row, "A").End(xlToLeft).Column` or `ActiveSheet.Cells(Cell3.row, "A").End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: The problem is not in that line of code, the problem start where i marked '`Fpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" `. This part of code till down doesn't execute at all, and before the same code executed everything smoothly.

Comment: You said the code worked before. Before what ?. What has changed since the code worked ? Note you are adding \ twice, once to Fpath and again with Filename = Dir( Fpath & "\\*"

Comment: Does the MsgBox get shown?

Comment: `FileName = Dir(Fpath & "\*" & CellName & ".xlsx")` - you already added the trailing `\ ` to `Fpath` and here you add *another* one, so you will not find the expected file